# Is there a way to implement horizontal timeline using Material UI in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timeline

I'm trying to implement a horizontal timeline using Material UI in React. In their documentation I could find only vertical timeline demos and I couldn't find any prop that can directly change the alignment. Is there a way to solve this?

I would want to implement something like the below image, but horizontal.

[image]

Comment: Has Google not given you any good ideas? When I searched I got some good results by searching `horizontal timelines ui`

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about your use case, because using a Stepper is might be the better (easier) approach.

Comment: @MikeW This question is about implementing it with this library (https://material-ui.com/) specifically.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden apologies - I missed that

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I've edited my post with more details. I too thought about stepper, but then I feel it would be complicated, since i can't use properties like align="alternate".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can override the timeline styles and do something like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  timeline: {
    transform: "rotate(90deg)"
  },
  timelineContentContainer: {
    textAlign: "left"
  },
  timelineContent: {
    display: "inline-block",
    transform: "rotate(-90deg)",
    textAlign: "center",
    minWidth: 50
  },
  timelineIcon: {
    transform: "rotate(-90deg)"
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Timeline className={classes.timeline} align="alternate">
      <TimelineItem>
        <TimelineSeparator>
          <CheckCircleOutlineIcon
            color="primary"
            className={classes.timelineIcon}
          />
          <TimelineConnector />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent className={classes.timelineContentContainer}>
          <Paper className={classes.timelineContent}>
            <Typography>Eat</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </TimelineContent>
      </TimelineItem>
      <TimelineItem>
        <TimelineSeparator>
          <PauseCircleFilledIcon
            color="primary"
            className={classes.timelineIcon}
          />
          <TimelineConnector />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent className={classes.timelineContentContainer}>
          <Paper className={classes.timelineContent}>
            <Typography>Code</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </TimelineContent>
      </TimelineItem>
      <TimelineItem>
        <TimelineSeparator>
          <CachedIcon color="primary" className={classes.timelineIcon} />
          <TimelineConnector />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent className={classes.timelineContentContainer}>
          <Paper className={classes.timelineContent}>
            <Typography>Sleep</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </TimelineContent>
      </TimelineItem>
      <TimelineItem>
        <TimelineSeparator>
          <CachedIcon color="primary" className={classes.timelineIcon} />
          <TimelineConnector />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent className={classes.timelineContentContainer}>
          <Paper className={classes.timelineContent}>
            <Typography>Repeat</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </TimelineContent>
      </TimelineItem>
      <TimelineItem>
        <TimelineSeparator>
          <ErrorIcon color="primary" className={classes.timelineIcon} />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent className={classes.timelineContentContainer}>
          <Paper className={classes.timelineContent}>
            <Typography>Sleep</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </TimelineContent>
      </TimelineItem>
    </Timeline>
  );
}
```

If the labels aren't on the same elevation, adjust `minWidth`.

---

The result looks like this:

[image: timeline]

One thing that will feel weird using this approach is that the visually left most element is the last element in the timeline, because of the rotation.

Answer (score 14):

If you like, you can use stepper as an alternative solution

[Material UI stepper](https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/)

Comment: Steppers are not a good choice if you need to put a description for each `TimelineItem`.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of UX, a timeline is most likely vertical. However, Mui stepper might be the one that you need: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stepper/.

You can opt in for an alternativeLabel and add content with StepLabel.